# Как по нажатию кнопки перейти на другую страницу?

Tags: jquery, html

Есть кнопка

```
<div class="field">
    <button name="write" class="j-submit-report">Написать отчет</button>
</div>
```

По ее нажатию надо перейти на странцу "report.php". Пытаюсь делать так

```
$('#write').click(function () {
    header("Location: report.php");
});
```

но не получается, подскажите что не так.

Comment: вижу что $('#write') ,а у вас есть атрибут Name=write но никак не  id.А header("Location: report.php");не нужно окружать <?php

Comment: изменила на id//
только не окружать header("Location: report.php"); php..как же..
ксли все это в файле registr.js?

Answer (score 7):

Попробуйте это:

```
<div class="field">
    <button name="write" class="j-submit-report" onclick="window.location.href='report.php'">Написать отчет</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button[name="write"]').click(function () {
    location.href = "report.php";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
    <button name="write" class="j-submit-report">Написать отчет</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, не импортирована библиотека jQuery. Я сделал всё без той библиотеки именно так, как Вы хотели

```
document.getElementsByName("write")[0].onclick = function(){window.location.href='report.php'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой подход - особенно если кнопок много и есть желание писать программер-френдли код:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field">
    <button url="https://stacksnippets.net">stacksnippets.net</button>
    <button url="https://stacksnippets.net">stacksnippets.net</button>
    <button url="https://stacksnippets.net">stacksnippets.net</button>
</div>

<script>
    $('button').on('click', function(){     
     window.location.href = $(this).attr('url');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ради одной строчки подключать целое `jquery`?

Comment: а чем этот ответ отличается от трех таких же уже данных ответов?

Comment: @ThisMan, jQuery уже используется в самом вопросе, так что это не так страшно

Comment: @Grundy отличается тем что у кнопки прописывается прозрачный и понятный атрибут и когда этих кнопок несколько (а то и несколько десятков) работа при подобном подходе упрощается. Многие крупные сайты используют сейчас подобный подход - прописать в тэги дополнительные атрибуты и оперировать скриптами с ними.